Save cards of customer razorpay
i want to save cards of customer when they pay for orders...
My flow is as follows

customer and order are created from server when order is placed from app.

payment is created from the app ( passing the key value pair "save": true in payload )

fetching tokens of customer by customer id while verifying payment from server


My issue is i am not getting token.
here i am giving my code snippet.
 $api = new Api($razorpayKey, $razorpaySecret);
 $tokens =  $api->customer->fetch($user->pg_cust_id)->tokens()->all();

Log::debug("tokens:- " . json_encode($tokens));

i am using razorpay library for laravel, but i am not getting any tokens.i printed tokens as above. its getting NULL.

provide more information about the controller,model,what the error is about and what you want

If you want to store card details, don't do it. You can't do it, you are not allowed to do so. You should have proper expertise and certification for that. And you should be registered as an official payment platform.

i dont want to store card detsils , i want to store only card tokens. but i am not getting any tokens.
